# How to get rid of error in Angular2: "if x is an ng component, verify it is part of this module"

Tags: angular

Previously in "How to import component into another root component in Angular 2" a similar question was raised but it doesn't answer my question since I had already added my component to declarations, etc.Here is the error message I'm receiving, and my question is, how do I get rid of it:
"Template parse errors:
'map-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'map-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'map-component' is a Web Component then add \"CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA\" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (\"
     
        {{ extra }}
        [ERROR ->]

Here's my code in app.module:

```
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    UserFormComponent,
    MapComponent
 ],
```

and then from map.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'map-component',
  template: `
    <div class="map">
    <h4>My message about the map</h4></div>
    `,
  styles: [
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
  ]
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

Thank you, this is my first time working with this framework and I really appreciate any insights.

Comment: What is your question? If the question is about an error, what is the exact and complete error message?

Comment: I just edited my original question to include the complete error message. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the posted code. Try replicating the problem in a plnkr.